# On scrolling Listview the items are changing their background to green

Tags: android, listview

I'm working with nfc tags that when I scan a nfc tag, tag content  stored in `string` and match the `string` with `listview` contents if the string matches with listview contents then the background of the `listview` item color changes to green.

I already wrote the code to get tag content in to a string I have `listview` in which there are some contents if the tag content matches with the content in the `Listview` it turns the background `listview` item color into green, the problem we got is that Even though a single compartment is being scanned multiple items are turning green but when clicking on done `button` only the scannned compartment is being registered Its just happening when we scroll

Here is the code :

```
public class Main15Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView l1;
TextView t1;


Button b1;
String tagcontent,rname;
Context ctx = this;
Databaseop mydb;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
ArrayList<String> theList,arrayList;
int flag=0;
Databaseop dp;
int counter;
int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main15);

    l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview3);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
    //b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button30);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "NFC NOT supported on this devices!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "NFC NOT Enabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS));
        finish();
    }
    mydb = new Databaseop(Main15Activity.this);
    final String rname = getIntent().getStringExtra("rname");
    t1.setText(rname);
    dp = new Databaseop(ctx);
    mydb = new Databaseop(Main15Activity.this);

    Cursor data = mydb.getListContents(dp, rname);
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast tos=Toast.makeText(Main15Activity.this, "There are no contents in this list!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        tos.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) tos.getView();
        TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
        toastTV.setTextSize(20);
        tos.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        tos.show();;
    } else {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            String theListcon = data.getString(0);
            Intent intent=getIntent();
            //String user=intent.getStringExtra("name");
            final String rid=intent.getStringExtra("rid");
            final String[] contents = convertStringToArray(theListcon);
            for (int j = 0; j <= contents.length - 1; j++) {
                String cmp=contents[j];
                dp = new Databaseop(ctx);
                dp.reports2(dp,rid,cmp);
            }
            //arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(contents));


            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,contents){
                public View getView(int position , View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                View view=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView textView=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                //textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                   String content=getItem(position);

                            if(content.equals(tagcontent))
                         {
                        //  int dkgrn=006400;
                        textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DARKGREEN));
                        Databaseop dp = new Databaseop(ctx);
                        dp.repoupdt(dp,tagcontent,rid);
                        Toast tos1= Toast.makeText(Main15Activity.this,tagcontent+" is Visited",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        tos1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) tos1.getView();
                        TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
                        toastTV.setTextSize(20);
                        tos1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
                        tos1.show();
                         }
                    //Toast.makeText(Main15Activity.this, "Location not on route", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                return view;
            }

            };

            l1.setAdapter(listAdapter);








        }


    }
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent=getIntent();
            String rid=intent.getStringExtra("rid");
            Cursor data1 = dp.getstatcnt(Integer.parseInt(rid));
            data1.moveToNext();
            final int theListcon = Integer.parseInt(data1.getString(0));
            final int j= l1.getAdapter().getCount();
            dp.updatereport(dp,rid,theListcon,j);
            dp.updateendtime(dp,rid);


            new AlertDialog.Builder(Main15Activity.this).setTitle("Warning")
                    .setMessage("Viseted "+theListcon+" out of "+j+ " Compartments \n Are you sure you want to end rounds?")
                    .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(Main15Activity.this, ""+theListcon+"/"+j,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i=new Intent(Main15Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

        }
    });


}

public static String strSeparator = ", ";

public static String[] convertStringToArray(String str) {
    String[] arr = str.split(strSeparator);
    return arr;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if (tag == null) {Toast.makeText(this,"no ndef message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Parcelable[] parcelables=intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if(parcelables!=null && parcelables.length>0){
            readTextFromTag((NdefMessage)parcelables[0]);
        }else{Toast.makeText(this,"no ndef message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}


    }



    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

private void readTextFromTag(NdefMessage ndefMessage) {
    NdefRecord[] ndefRecords=ndefMessage.getRecords();
    if(ndefRecords!=null&&ndefRecords.length>0){
        NdefRecord ndefRecord=ndefRecords[0];
        String tagcontent=gettextfromNdefrecord(ndefRecord);


    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"no ndef message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main15Activity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    IntentFilter[] intentFilters = new IntentFilter[]{};
    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null);
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    super.onPause();
}

public String gettextfromNdefrecord(NdefRecord ndefRecord) {
    try {

        byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();
        String textencoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
        int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
        tagcontent = new String(payload, languageSize+1, payload.length - languageSize-1 , textencoding);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("gettextfromndefrecord", e.getMessage(), e);

    }

    return tagcontent;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Simply Do noting!
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Main15Activity.this,"you cannot go back from here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
    TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
    toastTV.setTextSize(20);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Comment: one thing you should keep in mind while doing selection type things in listview or recyclerview. You should always write else part of the condition too. And in that set the values to default.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for other case too

You're setting the background color for a condition and you should set another color for the latter condition.

```
 if(content.equals(tagcontent)){

          textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DARKGREEN));
}

else{

   textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
}
```

Comment: Sir, I have tried that  by writing else part also but didn't got the solution for my problem.

Comment: This solution is working but what i want is that there will be multiple tags scanned so the state should be retained i.e if a new tag is scanned the previously scanned tag is changing back to red and and the currently scanned tag is changing to greeen what  i want is that already turned green items must remain green.

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to restore the states even after closing the app and reopening again?

Comment: No i want all the items which were scanned to turn green And rest should remain red.